# PHP - How can I use the super global $_REQUEST array to resubmit a request to the server?

Tags: php, caching

I am looking for a way to programatically update cached files in my web application.

### Here is how it currently works

1. A request is made to my application
2. The request array is hashed using `md5()`. This gives me a unique `$requestID`
3. The cached directory is checked to see if a cache page exists for this request (the file name is `$requestID . '_' . $expiration`
4. If a cached page does exist, the expiration time (which is prepended to the file name) is analyzed.

   - If the cached page has not expired, it is returned to the user immediately.
5. If the cached page has expired, or if a cached page did not exist, the request is handled normally, and the page that is built is cached for the next request.

In addition to caching the page, I also save the `$_REQUEST` array to a separate file (`requests.json` below) so I can resubmit the request later on from a cronjob (updating the cache programmatically).

The cache directory looks like this.

```
/cache
    /cached_page_1
    /cached_page_2
    /cached_page_3
    /cached_page_4
    /requests.json
```

### Here is what I am trying to do

`requests.json` is a json string that maps `requestIDs` (each unique request made to my application) to `$_REQUEST` arrays.

```
array (size=3)
  'requestID' => string '6a8d36967bd6c409b75b3667d364e0b2' (length=32)
  'cachedFile' => string 'cache/cached_page_1' (length=80)
  'requestArr' => 
    array (size=2)
      'q' => string '/mysite/blog' (length=20)
      'title' => string 'Programming in PHP' (length=11)
```

I want to build a cron job that utilizes this data in the following way.

1. Deletes all of the files in the `cache` directory. This will ensure that **step 5** in the process above will called.
2. Uses the `$_REQUEST` array (stored in `requestArr`) to resubmit the request to the server.

Once the request is resubmitted, all of the pages in the cache will be updated.

### Question

- How can I use the super global `$_REQUEST` array to resubmit a request to the server?

Comment: whats in the $_REQUEST array that you want to resubmit - this all sounds a little weird

Comment: Just all of the GET and POST data that was sent. I am trying to duplicate the exact request that was made when a file was cached, and resubmit it to update the cached content

Comment: if you processed it it the first time, you already have the data, whats the big picture here?

Comment: Why replay to generate your cache? Why not crate a hash of the request (or at least the meaningful data in the request) and use that as the key lookup for your cache?

Comment: I have updated my question with a specific example of what I am trying to do with the $_REQUEST array

Comment: Separately save GET, POST and COOKIE variables, but ask yourself if this is a good idea first :p

Comment: thanks for the edit, thats a lot better question

Comment: No problem, I edited it one last time. I think it should be a little more clear now. Sorry about that